# Loading the MySql module for Python 3.6 (Windows)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to load the MySQL module in Python. However, I am having trouble getting started with this. My laptop is an Intel i5 with Windows 7.

I have both Python 3.6 and 3.7 installed - both 64 bit versions. I started with 3.7 and Visual Studio added 3.6 so I switched to using 3.6 since the wheel for mysqlclient seemed to be for Python 3.6.
I am using Pycharm IDE which I can use either versions of Python.

#### Installation via pip

I have tried `pip install mysqlclient` (calling from python directory) and I get the following error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file mysql.h
```

#### Installation via wheel

If I try to use the wheel `mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
which I put in the python directory and call

```
pip install mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

I get the following error:

```
mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

#### Other things I have tried

I installed Visual Studio 2017 as suggested in another response. That response suggest using Visual Studio 2015 though (would that make a difference)?

I also tried the MySQL connector at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
but this only seems to work with Python 3.4 and when run it is says `no Python 3.4 found`.

So I am running out of ideas. I have looked at several other answers and hence tried some the things already. Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to reformat your question so that the code is highlighted (this can be done by indenting in by 4 spaces or wrapping it in backticks). This makes it a lot easier to read. I also added some headers to separate the different things you already tried. Additionally, using the python-tag (instead of the version-specific python-3.x tag) gives your question a lot more visibility. Good luck!

Comment: Concerning your question, I would recommend using a package manager like [conda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) to handle your Python packages. This makes installing packages a lot easier, since conda handles most dependency issues for you. If you are interested in this you can find a tutorial [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with my question.  I tried miniconda with no success but I am not sure I understood how to use it properly. I did get as far as getting it to try to load MySQLdb / mysqlclient but this came back with not found